# How to validate properties/custom configuration files?

Tags: java, ant, configuration, properties, directory

My application has many properties/text configuration files. Is there a common way to validate these kind of files? May be some tools or something like xsd?
The files are large (more 1000 rows), so I frequently make mistake. Information in file in majority of cases - is path to different directories. So it will be good if they exist and are consistent. E.g.
if I have

```
mydata.root="c:\data"
```

and after I have:

```
myreports=${mydata.root}/reports
```

that will be good check that c:\data and c:\data\report exist

and not written (some hundreds rows down) e.g.

```
myreports=${mdata.root}/reports
```

Comment: This `${}` thing only works in Ant process; that is, it doesn't work from a simple `.properties` file if it is outside of Ant process. It won't work using `load()` method of Java `Properties` class. Anyway, you can check the existence of a file/folder in a Ant process as follows [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163998/do-i-have-any-way-to-check-the-existence-of-a-directory-in-ant-not-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163998/do-i-have-any-way-to-check-the-existence-of-a-directory-in-ant-not-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this validation in your build file.

For example, the following build file defines a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) `validate-file-property` which validates that a specified property is defined and that it exists as a file or dir in the file system.

```
<project default="init">

  <property file="test.properties"/>

  <target name="init">
    <validate-file-property property="program.files" type="dir"/>
    <validate-file-property property="mydata.root" type="dir"/>
    <validate-file-property property="foo"/>
  </target>

  <macrodef name="validate-file-property">
    <attribute name="property"/>
    <attribute name="type" default="file"/>
    <sequential>
      <fail unless="@{property}" message="The property '@{property}' is undefinded."/>
      <available file="${@{property}}" property="@{property}.exists" type="@{type}"/>
      <fail unless="@{property}.exists" message="The @{type} '@{property}' with value '${@{property}}' does not exist."/>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

</project>
```

You need to decide when to validate the properties, and you need to validate them explicitly - as shown in the `init` target in this example.

BTW, if you used a standardized pattern to name properties which refer to files or directories - e.g. `my.special.file`, `my.build.dir` - then you could use a shell script to discover all relevant properties and write all your `validate-file-property` elements . Something like this:

```
awk -F= '/\.(file|dir)/{ printf "<validate-file-property property=\"%s\" type=\"%s\"/>\n", $1, gensub(/.*\.(file|dir)/, "\\1", "g", $1) }' *.properties
```

You could paste the output into your build file.

Answer (score 1):

I once offered a bounty for information on configuration languages other than XML that provide schema validation. Unfortunately, such configuration languages are few and far between.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079692/validating-files-having-tree-based-structures/) to the bountied question, in case you want to see the sparseness of the responses.