# Validation of a properties file loaded with Apache Configurations

Tags: java, validation, configuration, configuration-files

I'm looking for a Java configuration framework for one of our projects and [Apache Configurations](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) looks very promising.

I need to define rules about config files which are used by validation on loading. I see that Apache Configurations can do this with XML files because it can use XSD validation. However i haven't found anything similar for pure property files yet. What i need is something like defining an additional property file which contains the required rules. Say for example:

```
config.key.which.is.optional.and.int=optional,int
config.key.which.is.required.and.string=required,string
```

Is there any ready made solution for this? Or is there a similar framework to Apache Configurations which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any schema validation mechanisms for Java properties. Ten months ago (in May 2011), I offered a bounty for information on configuration languages other than XML that provide schema validation. Unfortunately, such configuration languages are few and far between.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079692/validating-files-having-tree-based-structures/) to the bountied question, in case you want to see the sparseness of the responses.

Comment: Thank you. I have to go with XML then.